# Compile error "expected: end of statement"

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following calcScores function written:

```
Function calcScores(category As String) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each Ctl In UserForm1.Controls
        If Ctl.Tag = category And TypeName(Ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            Dim box As MSForms.CheckBox
            Set box = Ctl
            If box.Value = True Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    calcScores = count
End Function
```

This function takes a tag named "category" as a string and then checks the form for all check boxes with that tag and counts the ones that are checked. I know it works and counts the right number, because I have slightly edited it to output it's value to a label on the form instead of returning it.

When I try to call it in another function like this:

```
Function sortScores()
    Dim scores(0 to 5) as Integer
    scores(0) = calcScores "rChk"
    **CODE CONTINUES**
End Function
```

I get an error that says "Expected: End of Statement" as soon as I leave the line that assigns the function's return to scores(0). calcScores is assigned before sortScores, and was succesfully called in a sub before using the same syntax.

Any idea what the error could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call you function like this

```
scores(0) = calcScores("rChk")
```

Functions are called like that. Subs are called by

```
subName argument
```

Comment: ...That worked...

I swear I did that before and it didn't work xD Thank you!

Comment: Functions are called like that. Subs are called by subName args.